Is my plan for moving the sink acceptable?
For jurisdiction purposes, I'm in Ohio.
I have a terrible kitchen I'm updating.  Where the sink currently is, I'm installing a dishwasher - the drain for the sink is in a wall penetration right behind the dishwasher (there are two drains and 2 wall penetrations for some reason, I've illustrated my best guess on how they connect in yellow).  Where the window currently is, I want to put a sink.

The red is the dishwasher, the blue is the sink.  Green is my proposed plumbing for the sink: it'll hide in the back of the cabinet until I penetrate the wall (rather than penetrating the external wall and risking freezing), then split into a drain and a vent portion.  The drain portion will go into the basement and connect to the existing drain, the vent will go up above the flood level and then over to connect to the existing vent.
The orange is the drain for the dishwasher, which will go along the back of the cabinets and follow the sink drain until it gets back to the sink trap so I don't have to trap it separately.  I plan on removing the additional yellow branch that I no longer need (the two-basin sink is plumbed individually for some reason - built in the 50s, maybe that was code then).
Anything I need to be aware of, or does my plan seem correct?

Plumbing aside, consider that with your plan, if you open the door to the dishwasher to load dishes, you cannot stand in front of the sink to rinse them.

Yeah. Keep the work triangle in mind. With a dishwasher it's a work rectangle, but it's an old concept.

Funny how people half way wash dishes before putting them into a dishwasher.  Adding a bit of soap to the rinse sink and using the second for rinsing, saves the wear and tear on the dishwasher.

@RMDman The illustration isn't perfect, in reality there will be a (bit narrow, but usable) place to stand between the sink and the open dishwasher (the dishwasher is actually farther to the left than illustrated).

@crip659 I only rinse solids off (rice, bits of greens, etc.) to keep the filter as clear as possible.


follow the sink drain until it gets back to the sink trap so I don't have to trap it separately. I plan on removing the additional yellow branch that I no longer need (the two-basin sink is plumbed individually for some reason - built in the 50s, maybe that was code then).

Trapping each drain separately (two in the sink, one from the dishwasher) helps keep them from feeding into each other if ever the drain becomes fully or partially blocked.  This includes the situation where the drain pipe (including the trap itself) is too small from the beginning.
I know that I've seen a plumber replace a shared trap like you describe with separate traps in the face of problems.  In general, they prefer to have as little horizontal drain travel as possible before the trap.  They'd rather have the travel after the trap so that the horizontal area where things are likely to stick is on the other side of the trap from the room.  That way you don't get a rotting food smell from the side before the trap.
Running a really long horizontal drain to a trap seems like a recipe for bad smells from rotting food in that drain.  That's even if you are careful about maintaining a downward slope.  People do similar things with flexible hose that they run into the sink drain, but they also have to clean or replace that hose as it fills up with gunk over time.
